# how to disable execute php file on some directories under /var/www/website1 on Ubuntu 10.0x

Tags: php, apache, text

I'm running Ubuntu 10.0x vps, and want to display php file as text file on some directories under /var/www/wordpress/public

I use AddType text/plain  java c cpp php

java, c, cpp are working, but not php,

any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: where did you added the AddType (.htaccess, apache confg file)?

Comment: any reason not to rename the file?